# Link inside MySQL string does not seem to work

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I tried to make a simple function in PHP that gets a link from a table in MySQL. Now my problem is that the link is not working..

**Details:**

My php file:

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = 'host.mysql';
    $mysql_username = 'username';
    $mysql_password = 'password';
    $mysql_dbname = 'db_name';

    $dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);     
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT team FROM user_info WHERE id = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $team = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    echo $team;
?>
```

The table is 'user_info', in my table I have two columns, 'id' and 'team'.

The 'id' is '1' and the 'team' should be

```
    <a href="team.php">Team Info</a>'
```

**Problem**

When I run this file there is no result. The '$team' is actually empty or does not want to work.. Any ideas?

I am shure there is no error in my php file because it is not the first time I'm using this and it worked before.

Comment: Are you sure id #1 has data associated with it?

Comment: @RUJordan Yes I'm really shure.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not 100% familiar with PDO. Try vardump()'ing your variables

Comment: @DonDjango What if you were to do `print ($team->id);` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still the same..

Comment: @DonDjango Try Jim's answer below then, see what that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of $team = $stmt->fetchColumn(); use:

```
    $team =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$link = $team['team'];
```

Comment: This does seem to work.. Can you explain why(if it is possible)??

Comment: this fetch's the specific item (team) and sets it to the variable link ($link).  just like if you were using MySQLi ($link = $row['team']).  You need to tell it specifically what you want to have returned.